# R using mapply to replace a nested loop

Tags: r

I am trying to use mapply to replace a nested loop.

I have a dataframe:

```
a <-rnorm(20)
b <-rnorm(20)
c <-rnorm(20)
d <-rnorm(20)
e <-rnorm(20)
f <-rnorm(20)

df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d,e,f)
df
```

I also have a function:

```
fnsum <-function(num1,num2)
{
 dsum <- sum(df[,num1],df[,num2])
 idx <- names(df[num1])
 idy <- names(df[num2])
 dsum1 <- data.frame(idx,idy,dsum)
 dsum1 
 return(dsum1)
}
```

I can use this function within a nested loop to obtain an answer:

```
len1 <- 6
dsumall <- fnsum(1,2)
for (n in 2:(len1-1)) {
    for (m in (n+1):len1) {

dsumall  <- rbind(dsumall ,fnsum(n,m))

}
}

dsumall
```

But I am problems getting mapply to work for a general solution applicable to any sized dataframe:

```
dsumall <- mapply(fnsum, n = 1:(len1-1), m = (n+1):len1)
dsumall
```

I would be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
num2 <- unlist(mapply(seq,from = 3:6,length.out = 4:1))
dsumall1 <- mapply(fnsum, 
                   num1 = c(1,rep(2:5,times = 4:1)), 
                   num2 = c(2,num2),
                   SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
do.call("rbind",dsumall1)
```